# Summing numbers don't match up?

Tags: sql

I have a table with data like this (acc_v in query):

| value | id |
| --- | --- |
| 100 | 1 |
| 300 | 2 |
| 200 | 1 |

As you can see there are multiple values per id. I want to sum all of the values across the ids and end up with this:

| value | id |
| --- | --- |
| 300 | 1 |
| 300 | 2 |

```
;with accV as (SELECT 
      d_id
      ,[period_end_date]
      ,max(a_value) as value
      ,id
  FROM bh
  where period_end_date = '2021-6-30'
  group by d_id, period_end_date, id)

SELECT bh.id, sum(value)
FROM bh join accV on accV.id = bh.id
group by bh.id
```

For some reason the total values are adding up to significantly larger amounts than they should be. I verified this by taking the original values and summing them in excel. If anyone knows what I am doing wrong the help is much appreciated.

Comment: I would query the 2 tables individually and verify the data is not returning something more than expected from the 2 tables for your sum.

Comment: already did that

Comment: Do your sun but group by ID.

Comment: oh I've already been doing that let me edit the post

Comment: Please provide your actual query, not your textual description of what you think you are doing. Unfortunately DBMS does exactly what you ask it to do, not what you assume it should do. SQL have no intelligence in its syntax, just rules

Comment: Just made the edits thanks for the feedback

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: My server is Microsoft sql. Unfortunately I can't access more info than that hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use window functions:

```
select id, sum(sum(value)) over () as total_sum
from t
group by id;
```

Comment: this did not fix it unfortunately